# Extract informations from ELF file

Tags: readelf

I use the Windows XP Operating System.

I cann't understand the logic by which readelf displays structures and unions.

Is there any method to extract all structures and unions from the ELF file using readelf ?

Comment: The executable format of Windows is [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

Comment: I generated the executable elf to load it into the target PowerPC family, and I would like to interpret it!